# Plotly: Displaying intermediate data between points on a hover

Tags: hover, plotly-dash, scatter-plot, plotly-python, x-axis

I encountered this problem when displaying data on the hover when I used `hovermode="x unified"`.
Since my data for three curves contains different values (months), the on hover we can see information to the nearest points.
But I need to output the exact value for First Second and Thirds line in the any month's point I'm pointing at.
I tried to solve the problem using:

```
 fig.update_xaxes(
            showspikes=True,
            spikecolor="grey",
            spikesnap="cursor",
            spikemode="across"
        )
```

It didn't help. Maybe you have some ideas on how to do this.
There is an option to add missing values along the X axis for each line, that is, make the same data for each line.
But maybe there is still a solution through the means of the flesh that I don’t know about?
Thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCBeN.png